# Разметить структуру typedef в памяти GPU с помощью CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

```
typedef struct {
    long    residue[n];
} rns;

rns ** A = new rns *[matrix_size];
for (int i = 0; i < matrix_size; i++)
        A[i] = new rns[matrix_size];
```

Эту структуру пытаюсь разметить в памяти GPU вот так:

```
cudaMalloc((void**)&A, matrix_size*sizeof(rns));
```

Работать с ней в функции `__global` не выходит, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Непонятно, что вы пытаетесь исполнить.  Вы выделили в C++ одномерный массив указателей на одномерные массивы и ...?

Comment: А Вы man/help по `cudaMalloc()` вообще читали? Там же написано -- "Allocates size bytes of **linear memory** on the device...". Т.е. скорее всего Вам надо пересмотреть **свою** организацию  матрицы (она д.б. плотной) и разместить данные (инициализировать матрицу) не в памяти, выделяемой `new`, а в памяти, адрес которой возвращает `cudaMalloc()`.

Comment: @avp cudaMalloc возвращает только тип cudaError_t разве нет?

Comment: Да, видимо я не совсем верно сказал. Правильней -- пишет адрес выделенной на устройстве памяти в переменную, на которую указывает ее первый аргумент. А что от этого меняется?  У Вас в `rns` был адрес памяти, выделенной по `new`. / После вызова `cudaMalloc` в ней другой адрес (старая "утекла"). Теперь надо правильно заполнить эту выделеную cuda память.

Comment: @avp я уже разметил с помощью cudaMallocPitch больше подходит для данного случая, как мне показалось